# Turn this into an if / else statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

When an item is chosen on my site, it opens a details page. This is the top of the details page above the html tags:

```
<?php require_once('dbconnection.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
$recordID = $_GET['recordID'];
$query_Master_details = "
SELECT * 
  FROM Master_List 
 WHERE Master_List.Master_Id = $recordID
";
$Master_details = mysqli_query($conn, $query_Master_details) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_Master_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Master_details);
$totalRows_Master_details = mysqli_num_rows($Master_details);
?>
```

This is the code that makes the body of the page:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_Master_details['Name']; ?></h2></div>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_Master_details['Img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Length']; ?> Characters</p>
    <?php
    mysqli_free_result($Master_details);
    ?>
<!-- end .container2 --></div>
```

What I would like to do is create an if/else statement that will look at the Style_ID of the selected item and determine if the number is > 3. If it is, I want it to choose an item that has a Style_Id of 1, 2, or 3 and the same Length as the item chosen and return a random row in the layout above, skip a few lines and then display the information for the selected item in the layout above. Else if it is < or = 3, then I need it to just display as above.

I have tried using:

```
    <?php
    If (Style_ID > 3) {
        echo 'Test';
    }Else {
    <div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_Master_details['Name']; ?></h2></div>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_Master_details['Img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_Master_details['Length']; ?> Characters</p>
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    mysqli_free_result($Master_details);
    ?>
```

But it doesn't work and has syntax errors. How can I create this if/else statement?

Note: I would appreciate being able to get one setup for all of it, but if not just fixing this part would be a big help right now.

Comment: Just so you know the test was just to see if I could make the second part work before I went into getting the array and random row.

Comment: This code is incredibly insecure.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.  Additionally, never inject arbitrary text into HTML or you're opening yourself up to other attacks as well.  Use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @Brad, I am not sure I understand what you mean by any of that. Right now, I am just trying to build the site and the site is in PHP. However, even with PHP you have HTML header tags.

Comment: Basically, ignore whomever/wherever taught you to do your queries this way.  Someone can pass their own SQL to your `recordID` parameter and run whatever SQL they want on your database, stealing data, locking things up, possibly running system commands depending on how the database is set up.  The problem is that *data* (`$_GET['recordID']`) is mixed with the *command* (your SQL `SELECT` query).  To fix the problem, you need to fundamentally separate the two.  To do this correctly, use SQL parameters:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The second problem (inserting text into HTML) is much the same sort of issue.  You have some text (like `$row_Master_details[Name']`) that could contain reserved characters in HTML.  To use them properly in HTML, you need to "escape" them, which replaces reserved characters (like `<`) with their appropriate entities (like `&lt;`).  Otherwise, you risk generating invalid HTML or even security issues.  (Suppose someone has a username called `<script src="something-evil.js">`.  They can inject code right into your site!)

Comment: @Brad, I don't know if it makes a difference, but the information that is being called is coming from a database that I am building not from outside sources. The only outside source is when someone clicks on an image in the site that is a link.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, for either problem.  For the SQL injection issue, there are automated bots trolling websites looking for problems like this, and they'll definitely find it.  If you ever check your server logs, you'll see them looking.  For the injection-int-HTML issue, it's only a matter of time before you'll be generating invalid HTML.  Do it correctly now, before you have a serious issue on your hands.  it isn't more difficult, and doesn't take any extra time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Brad for his responses, I finally got this one figured out. I ended up changing some of my field names and finally figured out where to close the php tags to make this work. Here is what I ended up with:

```
    <div class="container2">
  <div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></h2></div>
  <?php
  if ($row_master_details['type_id'] > 3) {
      echo "Test";
  }else { ?>
  <p><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></p>
  <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_master_details['img']; ?>" /></p>
  <p><?php echo $row_master_details['item_code']; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row_master_details['length']; ?> Characters</p>
  <?php
  mysqli_free_result($master_details);
  ?>
  <?php } ?>
<!-- end .container2 --></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

For starters, PHP is case-sensitive.

```
If (...) {
    ...
}Else {
```

You'll want to use lower-case `if` and `else`.

Next, if `Style_ID` is an attribute of the record, you'll need to access it like you did the others.

```
if ($row_Master_details['Style_ID'] > 3) {
```

Comment: After fixing that, I have those, now it is saying I have a syntax error on the line that says "<div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_Master_details['Name']; ?></h2></div>". This is the same problem I was having. It doesn't seem to like the php inside the if/else tags.
.

Comment: @JoAnnMoak You need to actually close your PHP tag before you start using HTML again.  At least in what you have above, there's no `?>` before your `<div...`.

Comment: I moved the div class above the opening php tags, but now it is saying the issue is with the next line down. Even if I remove the p tags it still claims to have a syntax error there.

Comment: You can't use HTML within your PHP tags.  You need to close your PHP tags before putting in HTML.  You can do something like this:  `<?php if (true) { ?> <h1>Some HTML here!</h1> <?php } ?>`  Honestly, the code formatting gets pretty messy.  I usually recommend using a template engine, but if  you don't need that, you can just echo out your HTML as well, from PHP.  It makes things easier to keep track of.

Comment: Pretty much if I can get it to do something similar to what I have, I am fine. I just need the Name, Img, Item_Code, and Length to display like a column on the page.